# Why does he say that there is a selfie squared in this photo?

Tags: expressions

[image]

So why is Dr.Gregory Sadler saying this image could be described as a selfie squared?

I.e why is taking a selfie of a selfie like the comment on this picture states a selfie squared? Why does the fact that there being a selfie within a selfie make it as if one is squaring a number in mathematics?

Comment: He says why: it's a selfie of a selfie.

Comment: Yeah I know that but why does selfie of a selfie mean a selfie squared?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a maths joke.

If I have seven bags, and each bag has seven cats, then there are seven-squared (=49) cats.  That is because 7 of 7 is 7²

Similarly if I have a function *f(x)* and I compose it with itself to get *f(f(x))* I might call the resulting function *f²(x)*.  Because *f* of *f* of *x* is *f*-squared of *x*.

But here there is "A selfie of a selfie" and by joking analogy that is (selfie)².  But it is only a joke.